# Build Pandas DataFrame from a list array with new column as list names

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, list

I would like to convert a list of arrays of varying array shapes like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [np.array([[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [1, 1, 2]]),
        np.array([[1, 3, 3], [2, 1, 2]]),
        np.array([[1, 3, 4], [2, 1, 2], [1, 3, 2], [1, 1, 2]])]
```

and would like to convert this listed array into a pandas DataFrame as:

```
|  element1  |  element2 | element3 | array_names |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | array1 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | array1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | array1 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | array2 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | array2 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | array3 |
```

With a new column is added as array names, but not sure how to proceed yet. Any inputs to deal with this? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary comprehension, [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)+[`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
out = (pd.concat({f'array{x}': pd.DataFrame(a) for x, a
                  in enumerate(data, start=1)},
                 names=['array_name'])
         .rename(columns=lambda x: f'element{x+1}')
         .reset_index(0)
      )
```

Output:

```
  array_name  element1  element2  element3
0     array1         1         2         3
1     array1         1         3         2
2     array1         1         1         2
0     array2         1         3         3
1     array2         2         1         2
0     array3         1         3         4
1     array3         2         1         2
2     array3         1         3         2
3     array3         1         1         2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, based on [`numpy.hstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) and [`numpy.vstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html):

1. Creates a new dataframe by `vstacking` all `data` arrays.
2. Creates an array with the names of the respective arrays.
3. Adds the arrays of names to the previously created dataframe.

```
    (pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(data), columns=[f'element{i+1}' for i in range(3)])
     .assign(array_names = np.hstack(
         [np.array([f'array{x+1}'] * len(y)) for x, y in enumerate(data)])
             .reshape(-1, 1)))
```

---

The above solution can be simplified, as suggested by @mozway in a comment below:

```
(pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(data), columns=[f'element{i+1}' for i in range(3)])
 .assign(array_names=[f'array{i+1}' for i, x in enumerate(data) 
                      for _ in range(len(x))]))
```

---

Output:

```
   element1  element2  element3 array_names
0         1         2         3      array1
1         1         3         2      array1
2         1         1         2      array1
3         1         3         3      array2
4         2         1         2      array2
5         1         3         4      array3
6         2         1         2      array3
7         1         3         2      array3
8         1         1         2      array3
```

Comment: You can simplify the last step to `.assign(array_names=[f'array{i+1}' for i, x in enumerate(data) for _ in range(len(x))])`

Comment: Indeed, @mozway! Thanks for having shared that!

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['array_names'] = ['array1', 'array2', 'array3']
df = df.explode(0)
df[['element1', 'element2', 'element3']] = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack(df[0]).transpose())
df = df.drop(0, axis=1)
```

The code does the following:

1. Creates a data frame
2. Adds your marker column (array1, array2, etc)
3. converts your arrays to rows per array element
4. explodes the array elements into columns
5. drops the excess column

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(pd.DataFrame(
    (v:=pd.Series(data).explode()).tolist(),index = v.index)
    .rename(lambda x: 'element{}'.format(x+1),axis=1)
    .assign(array_names = lambda x: 'array' + x.groupby(level=0).ngroup().add(1).astype(str)))
```

Output:

```
   element1  element2  element3 array_names
0         1         2         3      array1
0         1         3         2      array1
0         1         1         2      array1
1         1         3         3      array2
1         2         1         2      array2
2         1         3         4      array3
2         2         1         2      array3
2         1         3         2      array3
2         1         1         2      array3
```